# Draw image in specific coordinate

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want to make an app just like this http://andybest.net/2009/02/processing-opencv-tutorial-2-bubbles/ does in EMGU CV

the problem is, that I don't know how to draw multiple image in specific coordinate in emgu CV(or overlaying multiple image on top of captured image/video)

any help would be appreciated...

thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest thing you could use to blend a couple of images is to use AddWeighted function wrapped in emgucv.

For an overall introduction take a look at opencv [images adding](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) tutorial.
Here a couple of c# line codes that might help you:

```
    Image<Gray,Byte> result = new Image<Gray,Byte>(source.Size);
    CvInvoke.cvAddWeighted(source, movementFactor, overlay, 1.0-movementFactor, 0.0, result);
```